# How to export multiple files to database using shell script?

Tags: shell, sh

Hi everyone I have some files to be copied to database. but for every time  I should write "cp .csv'/tmp" so suggest me command in shell script so that I can copy all the files at once. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

file=/pathtoyour/textfile.txt

while read line
do
    cp $line /tmp/
done < $file
```

Comment: -bash: D:/testForShell/copyCommands.txt No such file or directory

Comment: If you are using Windows, shell scripts will not work

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. I will try with linux